# CakePHP with FullCalendar - events json strange problem

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, cakephp, fullcalendar

I have CakePHP 3.5.14. from FullCalendar v3. I moved the script to another server. The calendar has stopped working. I moved exactly.

When files were uploaded to the fullcalendar server it did not work. Calendar began to display only after importing from the URL. The calendar is empty. If I give him data directly from json it works. Import from url does not work. I asked the hosting provider - he replied that they are blocking nothing.

Current files:

Html->script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'); ?>

Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js');?>

Html->script('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js'); ?>

FullCalendar Script problem:

>$(document).ready(function() {
>   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>       header: {
>       left: 'prev,next today',
>       center: 'title',
>       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
>   },
>       locale: 'pl',
>     
>       defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
>       editable: true,
>       navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
>       eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
>       events: {
>           url: '/events/feed.json',
>       error: function() {
>               $('#script-warning').show();
>           }
>       },
>       loading: function(bool) {
>           $('#loading').toggle(bool);
>       }
>   });
>
>});


>

> 

FullCalendar Script it works:

```
> $(document).ready(function() {

>   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
>       header: {
>       left: 'prev,next today',
>       center: 'title',
>       right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
>   },
>       locale: 'pl',
>     
>       defaultDate: '2019-04-12',
>       editable: true,
>       navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
>       eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
>       events: [
>           {
>           title: 'All Day Event',
>           start: '2019-01-01'
>       },
>       {
>         title: 'Long Event',
>         start: '2019-01-07',
>         end: '2019-01-10'
>        },
>        {
>          id: 999,
>          title: 'Repeating Event',
>          start: '2019-01-09T16:00:00'
>        }

>      ]
>    });

>  });
```

My feed.json looks like this:

```
> [
>    {
>        "id": 1,
>        "title": "ccc",
>        "start": null,
>        "end": null,
>        "allDay": false,
>        "url": "\/events\/view\/1",
>        "details": "cccc",
>        "className": "Red"
>    },
>   {
>        "id": 4,
>        "title": "naprawa testowa",
>        "start": "2019-04-26T00:00:00+00:00",
>        "end": "2019-04-26T00:00:00+00:00",
>        "allDay": false,
>        "url": "\/events\/view\/4",
>        "details": "testowa",
>       "className": "Red"
>    }
> ]
```

Feed method:

```
> public function feed($id=null) {
>       $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');
>        $vars = $this->request->query([]);
>       $conditions = ['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)  $vars['end']];
>        $events = $this->Events->find('all', $conditions)->contain(['EventTypes']);

>       foreach($events as $event) {
>            if($event->all_day === 1) {
>                $allday = true;
>                $end = $event->start;
>            } else {
>                $allday = false;
>                $end = $event->end;
>           }
>           
>            $json[] = [
>                    'id' => $event->id,
>                   'title' => $event->title,
>                    'start'=> $event->start,
>                    'end' => $end,
>                    'allDay' => $allday,
>                   'url' => Router::url(['action' => 'view', $event->id]),
>                    'details' => $event->details,
>                    'className' => $event->event_type->color
>            ];
>       }

>   $this->set(compact('json'));
>   $this->set('_serialize', 'json');

>   }
```

I tried to encode the variable through PHP and change it to json in calendar script. Did not work. Please help. I miss ideas.

Comment: have you checked the CORS settings on the new server?

Comment: you'll have to give us more detail than "does not work". Please provide the results of your debugging work, so we (and you) can narrow down the problem.

Comment: The error logs are empty. CORS settings - I asked the hosting operator. I am waiting for a response.

Comment: have you checked what is being generated by the feed URL? Use your browser's Developer Tools to check the Console and also the Network tools, to see what is happening to the AJAX request, and what the response is

Comment: I have noticed: TypeError: t.start is undefined fullcalendar.min.js:6:25553, I do not see the json feed request in developer tools.

Comment: ADyson - Can I send you the website address?

Comment: did you manage to fix this? P.S. If you want someone to see your comments, you have to tag them with an @, like @Adam. I only came back here at random, looking through my history. I didn't know you had asked me a question.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson So the problem was the empty cell in the database with the start event date.